# How can I align the btn-group div to the top right?

Tags: html, css

This is the html I'm working with (which I cannot change):

```
<div class="article-summary media">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="media-heading">
      <a href="">
         Boosting SRL for Recommendation Systems
      </a>
    </h3>
    <div class="meta">
      <div class="authors">
        Kaushik Roy
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
        PDF
      </a>
      <a class="galley-link btn btn-default role=" button"="" file"="" href="">
        XML
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like now

[image]

This is how I want it to look

[image]

I'm trying to push the PDF|XML btn-group to the upper right. If the h3.media-heading is long, it should stop short of the btn-group and continue on the next line instead of pushing the btn-group down

Comment: You could use <table>

Comment: That would make it easy, but unfortunately, I'm not allowed to change the html, only css changes.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? If so, what version?

Comment: @SergChernata yes, it is bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current solution but I'm not sure if there are any side-effects I'm not thinking of

```
.media-body {
  position: relative;
}

.media-heading {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

.meta {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.media-body > div.btn-group {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Basically, I float all the .media-heading and .meta to the left, and I try to use absolute position to place the btn-group. I add a relative position to the btn-group's container, which is the .media-body because I learned that helps contain the absolute positioning of the element, otherwise, it flies out of the container and to the right of the entire page.